# ngCordova FileTransfer returning http_status: null when downloading file from FTP

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I am trying to download a file from a FTP server using Cordova. I have ngCordova and the Filetransfer plugins installed. Below is my code:

```
angular.module('TestApp', ['ionic', 'TestApp.controllers', 'charts.ng.justgage', 'pascalprecht.translate', 'ngCookies', 'ngCordova'])
var app = angular.module('TestApp.controllers', [])

app.controller('FileDownloadCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $cordovaFileTransfer) {
$scope.downloadFile = function() {
    var url = "ftp://URL/somefile.xml";
    var filename = url.split("/").pop();
    alert(filename);
    var targetPath = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + filename;
    var trustHosts = true;

    var options = new Object();
    var headers = { 'Authorization': 'Basic Login_cred' };
    options.headers = headers;

    alert(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory);
    alert(options.headers);
    $cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, options, trustHosts)
      .then(function(result) {
          // Success!
          alert(JSON.stringify(result));
      }, function(error) {
          // Error
          alert(JSON.stringify(error));
      }, function (progress) {
          $timeout(function () {
              $scope.downloadProgress = (progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100;
          })
      });
}
});
```

*Angular.module is located in a different JS file in the actual code*

This code returns the following alerts:

- somefile.xml
- file://storage/emulated/0/
- [object Object]
- {"code":2,"source":ftp://URL/somefile.xml","target":file:///storage/emulated/0/somefile.xml","http_status": null,"body":null,"exception":null}

I have tried downloading a file from a website hosted on the ftp (http://website/somefile.xml), which worked just fine. I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong with the header. I have also tried to put the Login_creds into the target url like this: ftp://username:password@URL/somefile.xml, this did not work but it could be browser specific.

Comment: Error Code 2 means Invalid source url, [see here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer#constants). Can you check the source url?

Comment: Hey Rahul, the URL seems correct, when used in my browser it links to the xml file on the ftp server (after entering login credentials).

Comment: can you try - encodeURI(url)

Comment: That ends up giving me the same error (code:2), I am starting to believe that it might be my FTP that is messing this up?

Comment: You can debug the issue using simple JQuery Ajax request or directly use the plugin code instead of ngCordova, see this - 

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer#example-1

Also make sure you have installed the plugin using this command

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer`

Answer (score 0):

ngCordova File Transfer does not work with ftp:// URL's, when I switched to a password protected http solution it worked.